# How do I determine if a variable is an Error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype, typeof

I have several variables mixed up in an array and some of them may be generic or custom errors (ie. generated by `var v = new Error()` or `var v = new MyCustomError()`).

Is there a generic way to differentiate an instance of Error from any other variable ? Thanks.

**Edit:** custom errors are in the form :

`function FacebookApiException(res) {
    this.name = "FacebookApiException";
    this.message = JSON.stringify(res || {});
    this.response = res;
}
FacebookApiException.prototype = Error.prototype;`

Comment: `instanceof` will do it.

Comment: Can you show us `MyCustomError`, please?

Comment: @Evan please add that to your question

Comment: Thank you all, instanceof does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, for the most part, use the `instanceof` operator, e.g.

```
var err = new Error();
if (err instanceof Error) {
  alert('That was an error!');
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg36M/1/).

The Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) has more details on the `instanceof` operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), stating that:

> *The `instanceof` operator tests presence of constructor.prototype in object prototype chain.*

Such that, given the following inputs you would get the outputs reflected in the comments:

```
function C(){} // defining a constructor
function D(){} // defining another constructor

var o = new C();
o instanceof C; // true, because: Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === C.prototype
o instanceof D; // false, because D.prototype is nowhere in o's prototype chain
o instanceof Object; // true, because:
C.prototype instanceof Object // true

C.prototype = {};
var o2 = new C();
o2 instanceof C; // true
o instanceof C; // false, because C.prototype is nowhere in o's prototype chain anymore

D.prototype = new C(); // use inheritance
var o3 = new D();
o3 instanceof D; // true
o3 instanceof C; // true
```

Comment: The second part of the answer is important: *instanceof* is OK provided you know the `[[Prototype]]` chain hasn't been tampered with and that objects can be "instances of" multiple constructors.

Answer (score 3):

your FacebookApiException doesn't inherit correctly from Error, I suggest doing something like this:

```
function FacebookApiException(res) {
    //re use Error constructor
    Error.call(this,JSON.stringify(res || {}));
    this.name = "FacebookApiException";
    this.response = res;
}
//Faceb... is an Error but Error is not Faceb...
//  so you can't set it's prototype to be equal to Error
FacebookApiException.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
//for completeness, not strictly needed but prototype.constructor
// is there automatically and should point to the right constructor
// re assigning the prototype has it pointing to Error but should be
// FacebookApiException
FacebookApiException.prototype.constructor = FacebookApiException;
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for pointing that out ! I'm really glad you made me discover Object.create().

Comment: The OP could also do `FacebookApiException.prototype = new Error()` and reset the *constructor* property, but the above is a better alternative.